# JPG files showing as PNG files

Tags: ios, png, jpeg

I have searched but can't find this question anywhere.  We created an iOS app that allows car dealers to take photos of cars and the images go up to the server.  Out of the blue, some of the jpg images are showing as png.  For example, in chrome, the image file is 56371.jpg, but when downloaded using safari, the image is 56371.jpg.png.  My question is, has anyone seen this happening using iOS  and why would safari show as png, but chrome jpg.  The file size for the .jpg.png ones are clearly larger than the standard jpg ones, so I am inclined to believe they are in fact png files.  I have a couple examples here....good jpg, http://img.awe.s3.amazonaws.com/1079/55594-1.jpg, bad jpg, http://img.awe.s3.amazonaws.com/1079/56371-1.jpg.

Comment: the second image is a png on both chrome and safari for me.

Comment: I don't think Safari/Chrome are doing anything to the image. Even tho the second image is named like a jpg, that doesn't mean the file is a jpg file. Look into how you're capturing and uploading the photos and if these photos have come from the same app.

Comment: No browser relies on the name of a file to decide on the file type. The browsers use the magic bytes of the file header to check for the file format. The filename is merely a hint only. You can check your files using imagemagick excellent tool identify: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

Comment: The first image is a JPG with a file extension of JPG. The second image is a PNG with a file extension of JPG. Does your iOS app check the file type, or does it just upload whatever image is selected by a user? Does your server check the file type, or does it just assign an extension of JPG to everything?

Comment: You don't describe the flow of the images through your system. At some point, something is setting the compression to PNG while creating a file with a JPG extension.

Comment: Here's what happens... we have an app we developed.  This app has been used for quite sometime, iOS.  We take the photos via the iOS app in which the images are immediately sent directly into the server.  Nothing else happens.  Yet some come across as actual jpg files (we check the exif info) and some as png.

Comment: @BrettDonald, we don't change anything, nor check anything as typically iOS would upload a jpg file and have not needed to.  I am wondering if something changed in the iOS sdk that now we have to specify.  It is just strange that some images are one way, some the other, not all or none type of thing.

Comment: If you take a photo with the camera, it is stored in camera roll as a JPG. If you take a screen shot (pressing Home and Lock simultaneously), it is stored in camera roll as a PNG. You can see this by plugging the device into a computer and browsing the images in camera roll. As far as I know it has always been like this.